# How to second last folder name using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I need to do the following:

1. Get the latest folder name from a directory and store it.
2. Get the latest-1 folder name from the same directory and store it.
3. Compare both.
   if latest > latest-1 , execute further steps.

E.g.:Folders list in a directory:

```
17731_17.00.00.00_26.01.0008
17731_17.00.00.00_26.01.0009
…
…
…
…
17731_17.00.00.00_26.01.0015
17731_17.00.00.00_27.01.0001
```

I am able to get latest folder name `17731_17.00.00.00_27.01.0001` using below code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir "<directory name>" /AD /O-N /B') do (set recent=%%A & goto exit)
:exit
echo %recent%
```

but I do not know if it is possible to get the `latest` `-1` folder name, `17731_17.00.00.00_26.01.0015`, to go forward with above steps.

My main goal is to determine when the version *(in this case `26`)* has changed, by comparing the number in folder name.

Please help.

Comment: The folder name represent a new version, increment and build. I have googled a lot and was unable to know if we can get the second last created folder name. :(
Will look into powershell.exe as you advised. Not expecting full code to be provided here.

Comment: If you're satisfied that the file list is ordered properly using `alphabetic` sorting, then the task is very simple, either reverse the sort order, skip the first item, choose the next and exit the loop; or leave the sort order the same, create a variable using the previous item returned, so that when you reach the last item, it is saving the second-last one.

Answer (score 1):

Taking account of my comments, the following examples should work for you, if you are certain that the target directory will always be the last but one named, from an ascending alphabetical sort order.

Here's an example using the first method, mentioned in my comment, *(reverse the sort order, skip the first item, choose the next and exit the loop)*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "LastButOne="
For /F "Skip=1 EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:D /O:-N <directory name>') Do Set "LastButOne=%%G"& GoTo Next
:Next
If Defined LastButOne Echo The alphabetically second-last directory name, is %LastButOne%& Pause
```

And this one uses the second method, mentioned in my comment. *(leave the sort order the same, create a variable using the previous item returned, so that when you reach the last item, it is saving the second-last one)*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "LastButOne="
Set "LastOne="
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:D /O:N <directory name>') Do (
    If Defined LastOne (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For %%H In ("!LastOne!") Do EndLocal & Set "LastButOne=%%~H"
    )
    Set "LastOne=%%G"
)
If Defined LastButOne (
    Echo The alphabetically second-last directory name, is %LastButOne%
    Pause
)
```

***In both cases, please remember to modify `<directory name>` as necessary.***